# what problem undefined variable on detail.blade.php?

Tags: laravel

getting undefined variable on detail.blade.php

route code

```
Route::get('/detail-data', 'calonMhs_controller@index');
```

controller code

```php
class calonMhs_controller extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {

        $mhs = CalonMhs::all();

        return view('/detail-data', compact('calonMhs')); 
    }
}
```

blade page code

```
@foreach ( $mhs as $cm )  { 
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h4>Data Pribadi Calon Mahasiswa</h4>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nama</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <p>{{ $cm->nama }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
@endforeach
```

i hope variable `$mhs` defined in blade page

Comment: Please don't get me wrong but you have to spend a little more effort the way you ask your question. Don't give the responder two problems, one to solve what you actually mean and two your main problem.

Answer (score 1):

Because you do not pass `$mhs` replace `compact('calonMhs')` to `compact('mhs')`

```
public function index() {

    $mhs = CalonMhs::all();

    return view('/detail-data', compact('mhs')); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```php
return view('/detail-data', compact('calonMhs'));
```

to:

```php
return view('/detail-data', compact('mhs'));
```

`compact()` accepts the name of the variable.